# Print "< .001" in table with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I have a table where one column are p values. p values should be formatted without leading zero, and if they are smaller than .001, they should be reported as "< .001".
Numbers should be aligned at the decimal point.

A similar question is here: [siunitx: Decimal alignment with 'less than' sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150535/siunitx-decimal-alignment-with-less-than-sign)

**But, how can I remove the leading zero?**

```
\documentclass{article}

%tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} %align numbers by decimal point

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format = 2]
  S[table-format = -1.2, table-space-text-post = $^{***}$]
  S[table-format = -1.2, table-space-text-post = $^{***}$]
  S[table-format = 2.2]
  S[table-format = <0.3]}
\toprule
{Item} & {$b$} & {$t$} & {$F$} & {$p$}\\
\midrule
1 & -1.45{$^{***}$} & -7.44{$^{***}$} & 55.34 & .18  \\
11 & -.86{$^{*}$} & -2.09{$^{*}$} & 4.36 & .01  \\
12 & -1.79{$^{***}$} & -3.80{$^{***}$} & 14.47 & .05  \\
13 & -.56 & -1.34 & 1.80 & .00  \\
61 & -1.79{$^{***}$} & -5.85{$^{***}$} & 34.20 & .12  \\
62 & -1.00{$^{**}$} & -3.17{$^{**}$} & 10.05 & .04  \\
63 & -.27 & -.65 & .43 & <0.001  \\
64 & -.37 & -.97 & .94 & .00  \\
65 & -.34 & -.85 & .73 & .00  \\
66 & 1.05{$^{**}$} & 2.70{$^{**}$} & 7.30 & .02  \\
67 & -1.12{$^{**}$} & -2.90{$^{**}$} & 8.40 & .03  \\
72 & -.41 & -1.20 & 1.43 & .00  \\
73 & -.27 & -.82 & .67 & .00  \\
74 & 2.05{$^{***}$} & 4.99{$^{***}$} & 24.88 & .09  \\
75 & 1.61{$^{***}$} & 4.41{$^{***}$} & 19.46 & .07  \\
76 & .29 & .91 & .83 & <0.001  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I correctly format the "p" column?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done by adding `add-integer-zero=false`, but you have to typeset your numbers without the leading zeroes, e.g. `<.001` instead of `<0.001`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} %align numbers by decimal point

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format = 2]
  S[table-format = -1.2, table-space-text-post = $^{***}$]
  S[table-format = -1.2, table-space-text-post = $^{***}$]
  S[table-format = 2.2]
  S[table-format = <0.3,add-integer-zero=false]}
\toprule
{Item} & {$b$} & {$t$} & {$F$} & {$p$}\\
\midrule
1 & -1.45{$^{***}$} & -7.44{$^{***}$} & 55.34 & .18  \\
11 & -.86{$^{*}$} & -2.09{$^{*}$} & 4.36 & .01  \\
12 & -1.79{$^{***}$} & -3.80{$^{***}$} & 14.47 & .05  \\
13 & -.56 & -1.34 & 1.80 & .00  \\
61 & -1.79{$^{***}$} & -5.85{$^{***}$} & 34.20 & .12  \\
62 & -1.00{$^{**}$} & -3.17{$^{**}$} & 10.05 & .04  \\
63 & -.27 & -.65 & .43 & <.001  \\
64 & -.37 & -.97 & .94 & .00  \\
65 & -.34 & -.85 & .73 & .00  \\
66 & 1.05{$^{**}$} & 2.70{$^{**}$} & 7.30 & .02  \\
67 & -1.12{$^{**}$} & -2.90{$^{**}$} & 8.40 & .03  \\
72 & -.41 & -1.20 & 1.43 & .00  \\
73 & -.27 & -.82 & .67 & .00  \\
74 & 2.05{$^{***}$} & 4.99{$^{***}$} & 24.88 & .09  \\
75 & 1.61{$^{***}$} & 4.41{$^{***}$} & 19.46 & .07  \\
76 & .29 & .91 & .83 & <.001  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Note, however, that removing the leading zero is not recommended at all, `siunitx` adds them because it is considered good typography.

Comment: "removing the leading zero is not recommended at all". I agree - but it's a requirement of the APA style guide for psychological science ...

Comment: @FelixS I see...

Comment: I think this must have changed (in version 3 of `siunits`?).  Instead of `add-integer-zero=false`, I had to use `print-zero-integer=false`.